# Any suggestions for a good login manager?

Tags: authentication, passwords

I tried using RoboForm but it's like Oracle - incredibly complex. We could never get it to share the corporate passwords but keep individual ones for each user.

Anyone know of a good login mananger?

We want one that has a shared company repository and individual repositories for each user for their person passwords. Preferably simple enough that there's only 5 - 10 options and only 1 password per user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at LastPass?  It allows sharing individual passwords, but not a complete repository of passwords (at least as far as I know) so it may not fit your needs.